# PHP - INSERT Query failing, returns no error. Beginner

Tags: php, sql

```
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
      <input type="text" id="link" name="link" />
      <input type="submit" value="Add resource" />
     <?php
      if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['link']) {
        $t = $_POST['title'];
        $l = $_POST['link'];

        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rman");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
          die("Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tutorials (id, title, link, section) VALUES ('','$t','$l','')");
      }
      ?>
  </form>
```

How can this not work? I have removed every single part that might have caused this. Nothing is going in the database, no errors returning whatsoever.

For everyone wondering:
DB name: rman
Table name: tutorials
colums: id (INT11, Auto increment), title (Text), link (Text), section(INT11)

Am I being blind here? I'm sorry if thats the situation. Hope someone can see what I am doing wrong and help me out.

Comment: check if you can pass null to section , actually i think you need to pass an integer value not null

Comment: does section allow null value? if yes you don't need to set a null or empty value to them.

Comment: You didn't check whether the query is failing or not. Make use of [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: Id is auto-increment, i think you shouldn't insert an id. Insert just title, link and section

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I removed every single part that could cause the problem because I was affraid that might have caused it. Still I get nothing in the databse, on all collumns the Null section is set to 'No' in phpmyadmin. My phpversion is 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, which was previously around 5. Could that be the problem?

Comment: try this : `mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tutorials VALUES ('$t','$l',1')");`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul weird

Comment: @vaxzz *all collumns the Null section is set to 'No'* is the problem. Make the *section* column as NULL(default). Also, since *id* column is auto incremented, you don't need to insert any value for this column. So your query should be like this: `mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tutorials (title, link, section) VALUES ('$t','$l',NULL)");`

Comment: @Sami What is weird here?

Comment: The answer is weird ,you can see my 1st comment ,bt the A does not slove it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use mysqli_error() to check error code, as well as don't insert blank id if it's AI

Thusly:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tutorials (id, title, link, section) VALUES ('','$t','$l','')")) 
{ 
    echo mysqli_error($con); 
}
```

Comment: if (!mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tutorials (id, title, link, section) VALUES ('','$t','$l','')")) {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}

Comment: Thank you for the help. I see others posted it aswell before but was away. I shouldn't have inserted id if it was auto increment, that was the problem.

Comment: @sziszu - It's best that you edit your answer to add the code from the comment

Comment: That check where is the error , bt not slove the issue

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['title']) && $_POST['link']) {
    $t = $_POST['title'];
    $l = $_POST['link'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rman");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die("Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tutorials (id, title, link, section) VALUES ('', '$t', '$l', '1')");
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
    <input type="text" id="link" name="link" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add resource" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should add some text explaining what was wrong with OPs code. Code-only answers are not well recepted.

Comment: Fixed. I'll remember.